# I am trying to install the next-auth@beta package and getting an error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am receiving the error:
code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:*

I have updated my node to the latest recommended version.

I was able to install the next auth package in the past on a different project. But, I just created a new Next.js 14 project and the first thing I try to do is install the next-auth package but it doesn't work.

I am able to install other npm packages and the next-auth version 4 package which was the previous package.

So, I am stuck and need help with installing this package.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the error you're facing might be related to compatibility issues or changes in the next-auth package. To resolve this, try installing a specific version of the next-auth package that is known to work with Next.js 14.

Run the following command in your project directory:

```
npm i next-auth@5.0.0-beta.4
```

This will install version 5.0.0-beta.4 of the next-auth package, which might be compatible with Next.js 14.

After running this command, check if the issue persists. If you encounter any further problems or have additional questions, feel free to ask for assistance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice, works for me, tq

Answer (score 0):

I was try.

5.0.0-beta.4 was installed.
But 5.0.0-beta.12 was not installed.

NPM version is 10.4.0
NODE version is v20.11.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).